# Can't run Selenium with C# after Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, dll

I made an application with C# that opens a browser with selenium but
when I run the setup there are some DLLs like System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.WebRequest
that can't be installed. Without them, the app does not open the browser therefore does not work.

During the setup build it says that they are excluded. What else can I do to make it work?

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

But when I run the app it doesn't open cause of the problem above

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want the app to open a specific Firefox window and enter the credentials given to login